# EclipseLink MOXy JSON Provider giving ClassCastException

Tags: json, classcastexception, moxy

I need to write code to process a REST request with a JSON message body as below.

```
[
  {
    "name": "Foo",
    "description": "An entity"
  },
  {
    "name": "Bar",
    "description": "Another entity"
  }
]
```

This is a JSON array of instances of the class below, that is to be serialized. The method that handles the request path (with the `@Path` annotation) takes an array argument. Method signature is: `public Response update(MyClass[] objects)`

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MyClass {

    @XmlAttribute
    String name;

    @XmlAttribute
    String description;

    // getters & setters
}
```

I am using Jersey 2.6 with `MOXyJsonProvider` on the server (with `MoxyJsonFeature` registered) but I get a ClassCastException:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: MyClass cannot be cast to javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement
    org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.readFrom(MOXyJsonProvider.java:598)
    org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:251)
    ....
```

The suggested fix in many posts is to add the `@XmlRootElement` annotation to the class but I already have that. Can someone please help me get this working? Thanks a lot.

EDIT: Appending additional information, in case it helps.

Stepping through the code where the exception occurs, I see that, in `org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider::readFrom` method, the `unmarshaller.unmarshal(....)` call (first line in the code extract below) returns a `JAXBElement` object with the `value` field being an `ArrayList` that contains the 2 `MyClass` instances that I want. The `if`-condition on next line evaluates to `false` so execution proceeds into the `else` clause. Since the `jaxbElement.getValue()` is an `ArrayList`, it is cast to `ArrayList<JAXBElement>`. Ultimately it gets into the for-loop at the end of the extract below, and calls `getValue()` on each item in `arrayList`, expecting each item to be a `JAXBElement`. But the actual items in the list are `MyClass` instances, and calling `getValue()` on the first item throws the `ClassCastException`.

I suspect that the fix would be some change in the annotations that I have in my `MyClass` definition.

```
       ....
        JAXBElement<?> jaxbElement = unmarshaller.unmarshal(jsonSource, domainClass);
        if(type.isAssignableFrom(JAXBElement.class)) {
            return jaxbElement;
        } else {
            Object value = jaxbElement.getValue();
            if(value instanceof ArrayList) {
                if(type.isArray()) {
                    ArrayList<JAXBElement> arrayList = (ArrayList<JAXBElement>) value;
                    int arrayListSize = arrayList.size();
                    Object array;
                    if(genericType instanceof GenericArrayType) {
                        array = Array.newInstance(JAXBElement.class, arrayListSize);
                        for(int x=0; x<arrayListSize; x++) {
                            Array.set(array, x, arrayList.get(x));
                        }
                    } else {
                        array = Array.newInstance(domainClass, arrayListSize);
                        for(int x=0; x<arrayListSize; x++) {
                            Array.set(array, x, arrayList.get(x).getValue());
                        // ^^^^^^^ In the above line, arrayList.get(x) is a
                        //  MyClass instance. It is not a JAXBElement
                        }
                    }
          ....
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working now after I changed the method signature from:

```
public Response update(MyClass[] objects)
```

to:

```
public Response update(List<MyClass> objects)
```

A co-worker told me to try that. Wish I'd asked him sooner. :(

So that solved my issue but I don't know if some different annotations in `MyClass` would have got it working and yielded an array instead of a list; or if this is a bug in the MOXyJsonProvider; or if there is custom code required to make it work with the array-type argument.